# check g++ version being used in Makefile

Tags: c++, unix, gcc, makefile

I was compiling some open source code, and it gave me the following error:

```
g++: error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o: No such file or directory
```

This suggests that the version being used is `4.1.2`. However, when I do: `which g++` , the output is : `/opt/gcc/4.9.2/bin/g++` . This suggests that 4.9.2 is being used. I am confused, can anybody help me understand what is going on? I have not done a lot of unix.

Comment: What is your output to `g++ -v` ?

Comment: gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)

Comment: There are too many missing details in your question to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I am new to this. Please tell me any additional detail you would require!

Comment: It would help if you could point us to the open source code you attempted to compile. Or post the Makefile.

Comment: You need to provide enough details for use to reproduce the problem on our environments and or clearly see the path of execution to see where things could go wrong. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am trying to compile kaldi . The Make file is too big and also the error is popping up in one of the recursive makes.

Comment: Just checking, have you followed the instructions from [here](http://kaldi.sourceforge.net/install.html) ?

Comment: Yeah, I have compiled it many times before, Facing this make error for the first time

Comment: Perhaps your makefile explicitly listed the 4.1.2 `crti.o` .

Comment: Your best option might be to post on the mailing list associated with the project

Comment: what happen after installing `gcc-devel` which provides the crti.o

Answer (score 1):

Your path `/opt/gcc/4.9.2/bin/g++` suggests that this is not the gcc that's packaged as a part of whatever Linux distribution (or Unix) you are using. Rather, this is a different version of gcc that was compiled and installed alongside with your distribution's gcc. gcc's typical path, on native Linux distributions, is `/usr/bin/g++`.

gcc is a very large, complicated, software package. It's expected that it gets built and configured as part of a native Linux distribution. It is certainly possible to configure and build a different version of gcc, to supplement the one that comes with the Linux distro. I've done it before, several process, but it is a long, complicated, painful process. There is no cookie-cutter recipe to do it, the details vary depending on the host Linux distribution.

It's a brand new experience, every time. Quite often, gcc's configure script gets some detail wrong, and one has to end up patching some part of gcc's configure script, in order to make gcc build correctly on the host distro.

And when things go wrong, you get typical results like this one -- a broken link path. Sometimes you end up having problems with the header files, or a few other things.

So, in order to build gcc one has to have extensive not just development experience, but also experience building large and complicated free software packages. In order to build gcc one has to also have extensive knowledge and understanding of the GNU toolchain that gets used to build gcc, and thousands of other free software packages: `autoconf`, `automake`, `libtool`, and, depending on the software package in question, perhaps a few others.

So, you need to get in contact with the team of experienced sysadmins or developers that originally built your custom install of gcc 4.9.2 and installed it in /opt, then show them this error you're having, and have them figure out how gcc got misconfigured so it ends up linking things wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to compile and run this program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << __VERSION__ << std::endl;
}
```

This will print the version of g++ used to compile the program.
Here `__VERSION__` is a macro defined by g++.